# SQLDeveloper: lowest paid employee for a specified manager. Sample code given

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to write a query to display manager no. and the lowestwages employee for manager. we discard wages less than 1k
So I tried writing a code for it but its giving me an error. I think I have to edit the FROM condition in the second line:

```
SELECT empno, sal
FROM emp a, emp b
WHERE   empno IN (SELECT boss.empno
                  FROM emp a, emp boss
                  WHERE a.super = boss.empno)
AND MIN(sal) >1000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.empno, min(e.sal)
FROM emp e, emp m
WHERE e.super = m.empno
GROUP BY m.empno
HAVING min(e.sal) > 1000
```

Basically doing a SELF JOIN on employee table and GROUPing BY manager and getting the MIN salary of employee.

Haven't tested it yet so it may need a bit of tweeking

Comment: but how would i make it descending order of salary?

Comment: Try adding `ORDER BY min(e.sal) DESC` after the `HAVING` clause. Or add an alias in the `SELECT` clause and change `min(e.sal)` to `min(e.sal) minsal` and then add `ORDER BY minsal DESC` after the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Oh my god! sorry about that man! I actually forgot to remove semi colon from something! Ur answer was perfect!